# Visual Code gives error that it cannot find Python on Mac Pro

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm running a Mac Pro 2021 model version 12.6. For some reason, my vscode will not run Python anymore when I tried using a program. I switched over to the cloud-based version for a while and now switched back to the application. It says that it could not find Python in my files. I believe both VSCode and my Mac are updated up to date. I installed python 3.11.0 for Mac, but no progress. I also tried running the update shell.command and the certificate commands as a part of the download in the vscode terminal, but it did not help. I also reinstalled the Python
v2022.16.1 Vscode extension and restarted the program. I still get the same error.

[image]

Explained above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> type "Python: Select interpreter" yet?

Usually, all installed Python interpreters show up here, and you can also enter a path to a Python interpreter on your system.

Comment: Yes I just did. I had two options python 3.11.0 64 bit from /usr/local/bin/python3 (recommended) and 3.9.6.64 bit /usr/bin/python3 (global). Tried selecting each one and then ran the code, no result.